# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to make a crawler in python by following an udacity course. I have this method `get_page()` which returns the content of the page.

```
def get_page(url):
    '''
    Open the given url and return the content of the page.
    '''

    data = urlopen(url)
    html = data.read()
    return html.decode('utf8')
```

the original method was just returning `data.read()`, but that way I could not do operations like `str.find()`. After a quick search I found out I need to decode the data. But now I get this error

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position
>   1: invalid start byte

I have found similar questions in SO but none of them were specifically for this. Please help.

Comment: Could you let me know what the `url` value is?

Comment: it could be any url. In this case it was google.co.in

Comment: According to the header, the page is encoded with `ISO-8859-1`, not `utf-8`.

Comment: then how can I determine in what encoding a particular page uses? because it can be different for different pages right??

Comment: Check `content-type` header.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to decode an invalid string.

The start byte of any valid UTF-8 string must be in the range of `0x00` to `0x7F`.
So `0x8B` is definitely invalid.
From [RFC3629 Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3):

> In UTF-8, characters from the U+0000..U+10FFFF range (the UTF-16 accessible range) are encoded using sequences of 1 to 4 octets. The only octet of a "sequence" of one has the higher-order bit set to 0, the remaining 7 bits being used to encode the character number.

You should post the string you are trying to decode.

Comment: this is actually a web page. for example if i pass http://google.co.in as `url` then i get this error 
>UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 9862: invalid start byte

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the page is encoded with other character encoding but 'utf-8'. So the start byte is invalid.
You could do this.

```
def get_page(self, url):
    if url is None:
        return None
    response=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    if response.getcode()!=200:
        print("Http code:",response.getcode())
        return None
    else:
        try:
            return response.read().decode('utf-8')
        except:
            return response.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Web servers often serve HTML pages with a Content-Type header that includes the encoding used to encoding the page.  The header might look this:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

We can inspect the content of this header to find the encoding to use to decode the page:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen        
    
def get_page(url):    
    """ Open the given url and return the content of the page."""    
    
    data = urlopen(url)    
    content_type = data.headers.get('content-type', '')    
    print(f'{content_type=}')    
    encoding = 'latin-1'    
    if 'charset' in content_type:    
        _, _, encoding = content_type.rpartition('=')    
        print(f'{encoding=}')    
    html = data.read()    
    return html.decode(encoding)
```

Using `requests` is similar:

```py
response = requests.get(url)
content_type = reponse.headers.get('content-type', '')
```

Latin-1 (or ISO-8859-1) is a safe default: it will always decode any bytes (though the result may not be useful).

If the server doesn't serve a content-type header you can try looking for a `<meta>` tag that specifies the encoding in the HTML.  Or pass the response bytes to [Beautiful Soup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#encodings) and let it try to guess the encoding.